# Convert Excel Array to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formula, code-conversion

I'm trying to convert an excel array to VBA. Any help would be appreciated:

```
{=IFERROR((MATCH('Surgery'!D10&'Surgery'!D11,'NCCI'!A1:A263469&'NCCI'!B1:B263469,0)),"")}
```

The Surgery worksheet is where the user inputs a list of codes and the NCCI worksheet is where the above array searches to find a match. It uses the two codes entered by the user to search in two columns on the NCCI worksheet to try and find where two codes are in the same row and returns the row number.

Comment: There is no question here, and if the question is "how do I convert this to vba?" it is too broad for this forum.  This site is about helping overcome specific problems with existing code.

Comment: Show us what you already have in VBA.  Also tell us what problem you are running into in doing this.  Just showing us an Excel formula does not tell us anything.

Comment: `Application.Evaluate(yourFunctionHere)`

Comment: Note: `Application.Evaluate` can be golfed to `[yourFunctionHere]` square-bracketed expressions.

Comment: @A.S.H - It does?  I've only used them sparingly but don't recall any issues.

Comment: My tip is write a UDF in VBA which does what the array formula would do - taking the four parameters. Then if you wish to call this from some kind of worksheet event, just call the function from the Worksheet event Sub with the 4 parameters.

Comment: Works both on the sheet and when evaluated from VBA for me...

Comment: Odd A.S.H, I'm not finding this behaviour... Evaluate works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some other array formulas, this one *does* work with `Application.Evaluate`, it only needs to "double up" the double-quotes inside.

```
Dim v
v = Application.Evaluate("=IFERROR(MATCH(J2&K2,A1:A4&B1:B4,0), """")")
Debug.Print v
```